# Dotnet CLI command fails to run DLL

Tags: .net-core, command-line-interface

This is probably something stupid I'm overlooking, but suddenly the dotnet CLI command fails to run my .Net Core Project DLL (>dotnet MyFrameworkDependent.dll). It runs fine locally but just doesn't do anything on the VM which is Win7Pro. I reinstalled .Net Core and 'dotnet' utility is there as I can run it with -help and other stuff in the admin command prompt. It just wouldn't do anything when I pass my DLL. It used to run with the previous version, but now - nothing! Not even any error or feedback. Any ideas on how I can troubleshoot this? Any clues are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Turned out there was some kinda problem with directory contents. I was able to run the DLL within the publish directory. I don't have time at the moment to investigate further, but if I get to it, I'll post details.

Answer (score 0):

**Windows Event viewer** may contain either of these errors

```
1603 == ERROR_INSTALL_FAILURE
1618 == ERROR_INSTALL_ALREADY_RUNNING
```

**Cause:**
This issue may occur if another program has not completed installing and a system reboot is required.

**Resolution:**
To resolve this issue, delete the strings, if any, in the `PendingFileRenameOperations` and `FileRenameOperations` registry keys.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but there were no errors in event log and the Pending... reg key didn't exist and FileName had no entry. Something wrong with the directory itself or for some reason I have to be within the 'publish' to run it. I tried to copy contents from publish up to container dir, but it still didn't work. I'm good for for now.